# Studying Spanish at school in a Spanish speaking country

Tags: diferencias-regionales

In the Spanish speaking country where you live or have been, up to what age/year level is it compulsory to study the Spanish language at school.

Where I live (English speaking country) it is compulsory to study English in High School until 6th form (year 12, when you are ~16-17 years old). So I wanted to know if it was the same or similar in a Spanish speaking country.

Please don't forget to mention what country you are from, thanks =)

**Edit:**

The reason behind asking this question is because in my experiences in Argentina, the vast majority of students I talked with had a very good knowledge of the Spanish language. In contrast, if you found a student in their ultimate or penultimate year of high school where I live, and asked them what a noun/verb/adjective etc was, they would struggle to answer you.

**Edit:**

Thanks for the comments, it seems like the average age that it is compulsory to study is about the same as in an English speaking country

Comment: It is the same in most countries. I'm not sure if this is a list question or not. :)

Comment: In Peru, you take "spanish" during 8 years, from 6-13 years old (grammar, ortography). At 6 years old you learn to write and read, by I think any 7 years old knows what a verb, adjective and noun are. We learn also how to conjugate verbs as in Spain, funny (when I studied at least). In high school, you take additionally three years of "Spanish literature", from 14-16. It's sad people seems to forget everything while writing in internet or Facebook.

Comment: In Spain from 6 to 15-16 (obligatory education), but if you keep with Bachillerato then until 17-18

Comment: Same here, at "estudios generales" (similar to "bachillerato") I had to take 9 credits in spanish (for a science major). This is after the obligatory education, the first two year of superior studies.

Comment: Where do you live? that results you mention are from private, public education or general? 
And I have to say, children of 17 years old not knowing well to tell apart nouns, verbs and adjectives? wow.

Comment: I live in New Zealand, Im talking about public education but I doubt private would be any different. I believe it is because we only study literature in 'English' class not the actually language itself. That and the fact that it is almost never compulsory to study a 2nd language (except in private schools) so they never teach these things.

Comment: The vast majority of South American countries before the age of 18 must have a good command of language, even many of you know a second language to handle a before leaving the school. And not to mention that to enter a university, you must have excellent management of writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chile you learn spanish from when you're 6 until you're 18. It varies from mostly orthography to vocabulary, grammar and literature. By the time you're 16 it is mostly just literature.